# User-Agent switcher for Firefox

Tags: firefox

I have been using the [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) add-on for Firefox. It's good but I need one that works on a per-domain basis.

[Override User Agent](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/override-user-agent/) promises that but won't work on Firefox 35 that I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Firefox addon that meets your requirements,

**[UAControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/uacontrol/)**
Control what gets sent as the User-Agent on a per-site basis.
[image: UAControl User Interface]